# Is $\mu$ a measure

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

[image]

a) $\mu(E)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\#[\{2,4,\dots\}\cap \{1,\dots,n\}]}{n}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n/2}{n}=1/2$ and $\mu(O)=1/2$ by same argument. $$\mu(S)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\#[ \{1,4,9,\dots\}\cap \{1,\dots,n\}]}{n}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\sqrt n}{n}=0$$

b) Let $A,B$ be disjoint sets in $\mathcal A$. $$\begin{split}\mu(A\cup B)&=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\#[(A\cup B)\cap \{1,\dots,n\}]}{n}&&\text{definition}\\
&=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\#[A\cap \{1,\dots,n\} \cup B \cap \{1,\dots,n\}]}{n}&&\text{DeMorgan's Law}\\
&=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\#[A\cap \{1,\dots,n\}] +\#[ B \cap \{1,\dots,n\}]}{n}&&\text{$A$ and $B$ are disjoint}\\
&=\mu(A)+\mu(B)\end{split}$$

c) The two requirements for a measure are

1. $\mu:\mathcal A\rightarrow[0,\infty]$. This is satisfied since $\mu(B)$ is between 0 and 1.
2. If $B_1,B_2,\dots$ are disjoint elements of $\mathcal A$ then $\mu\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty B_i\right)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \mu(B_i)$. This follows inductively from part 2.

I recognize this is a pretty simple exercise but have I made any big oversights?

Comment: It does not "follow inductively". What follows is that $\mu$ behaves well with any finite disjoint union, but not necessarily infinite disjoint union. Consider $B_i=\{i\}$.

Comment: We can prove inductively that $1+1+1+\cdots +1$ is a natural number, but that does not mean an infinite sum $1+1+\cdots$ is a natural number.

Comment: @Kushi Ahh thank you. I see from your counter example that $\mu$ is not a measure

Comment: @Thomas thank you for the analogy!